# How to print lines in certain order from different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Suppose we have a class:

```java
public class Foo {
  public void first() { print("first"); }
  public void second() { print("second"); }
  public void third() { print("third"); }
}
```

The same instance of Foo will be passed to three different threads. Thread A will call first(), thread B will call second(), and thread C will call third(). Design a mechanism and modify the program to ensure that second() is executed after first(), and third() is executed after second().

My full solution looks like:

```java
class Foo {

    int threadNumber;

    public Foo() {
        this.threadNumber = 1;
    }

    synchronized public void first(Runnable printFirst) throws InterruptedException {
        while (threadNumber != 1) {
            wait();
        }
        // printFirst.run() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
        printFirst.run();
        threadNumber++;
        notifyAll();
    }

    synchronized public void second(Runnable printSecond) throws InterruptedException {
        while (threadNumber != 2) {
            wait();
        }
        // printSecond.run() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
        printSecond.run();
        threadNumber++;
        notifyAll();
    }

    synchronized public void third(Runnable printThird) throws InterruptedException {
        while (threadNumber != 3) {
            wait();
        }
        // printThird.run() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
        printThird.run();
        threadNumber++;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Currently I don't understand how to pass Runnable object to the synchronized methods (it's one the task conditions):

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        CustomFirst customFirst = new CustomFirst();
        CustomSecond customSecond = new CustomSecond();
        CustomThird customThird = new CustomThird();

        try {
            foo.first(customFirst);
            foo.third(customThird);
            foo.second(customSecond);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it is a problem from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-in-order/).

> Currently I don't understand how to pass `Runnable` object to the synchronized methods (it's one the task conditions):

The `runnable` could look like:

```
private static class PrintingRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final String string;

    public PrintingRunnable(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.print(string);
    }
}
```

and passed as:

```
foo.first(new PrintingRunnable("first"));
foo.second(new PrintingRunnable("second"));
foo.third(new PrintingRunnable("third"));
```

---

Please note, that you are **not required** to supply your own `Runnable`s, or create `Thread`s to solve the problem, just implement the `first`, `second`, and `third` methods.

---

In Java, `Runnable` is *nothing more* than some action that could be [`run`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html#run()). It may print something, or do anything else.

It is possible that leetcode **does not really print anything**, but uses *something different to test submissions*. (And it does not matter for someone, who tries to solve the problem)

But if you want to do it locally you can use the `PrintingRunnable` above:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Foo foo = new Foo();


    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            foo.third(new PrintingRunnable("third"));
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            foo.first(new PrintingRunnable("first"));
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            foo.second(new PrintingRunnable("second"));
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An ad-hock implementation of such step-by-step scenario may be based on CountDownLatch primitive like following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class FooOrchestration {
    public static class Foo {
        public void first() { print("first"); }
        public void second() { print("second"); }
        public void third() { print("third"); }
    }

    static void print(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    static class Step extends Thread {
        private final CountDownLatch starter = new CountDownLatch(1);
        private final List<Step> nextSteps = new ArrayList<>();
        private final Runnable action;

        Step(final Runnable action) {
            this.action = action;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                starter.await(); // wait until someone kicks the starter with countDown()
                action.run();
                for (Step s : nextSteps) { // let's start the following steps
                    s.starter.countDown();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                for (Step s : nextSteps) { // let's propagate 
                    s.interrupt(); // the interruption
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        Step firstStep = new Step(() -> foo.first());
        Step secondStep = new Step(() -> foo.second());
        Step thirdStep = new Step(() -> foo.third());

        firstStep.nextSteps.add(secondStep); // set sequence
        secondStep.nextSteps.add(thirdStep); // of execution

        thirdStep.start(); // order of start
        secondStep.start(); // doesn't
        firstStep.start(); // matter

        firstStep.starter.countDown(); // kick the starterof the first step
    }
}
```

Also, the standard package java.concurrent provides more generic and flexible barrier Phaser https://www.baeldung.com/java-phaser which allows to build different and complex scenarios of multi-threading executions easily.